# Python, use "order by" inside a "group concat" with pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sql-order-by, group-concat

I have the following Pandas DataFrame:

```
product_id     category     number_of_purchase
23             cat1         18
65             cat2         19
66             cat1         4
98             cat1         9
998            cat1         1
798            cat2         8
```

And from this DataFrame I want to creat this new DataFrame:

```
category     url
cat1         65&23
cat2         65&8
```

(for each category I want to retrieve the 2 items having the most number of purchase)

In MySQL I would have done:

```
select
   category,
   group_concat(product_id order by numbe_of_purchase desc limit2 separator '&')
from my_table
group by category
```

but I don't know how to group_concat with Pandas DataFrame and also how to use an order by and a limit inside a group_concat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no group concat function in python / pandas, so we'll have to use some groupby. It's a bit longer than SQL, but still relatively short (main part is 3 lines).

Let's create the dataframe :

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'product_id': [23, 65, 66, 98, 998, 798],
        'category': ['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat1', 'cat1', 'cat1', 'cat2'],
        'number_of_purchase': [18,19,4,9,1,8]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print df
```

result :

```
  category  number_of_purchase  product_id
0     cat1                  18          23
1     cat2                  19          65
2     cat1                   4          66
3     cat1                   9          98
4     cat1                   1         998
5     cat2                   8         798
```

First step : we sort the dataframe by sales :

```
df = df.sort(columns='number_of_purchase', ascending=False)
df
```

result :

```
  category  number_of_purchase  product_id
1     cat2                  19          65
0     cat1                  18          23
3     cat1                   9          98
5     cat2                   8         798
2     cat1                   4          66
4     cat1                   1         998
```

Seconde step : We use a groupby operation.For each category, it will create a list of the top two categories. Data is still integer.

```
df = df.groupby('category').apply(lambda x: list(x.product_id)[:2])
print df
```

result :

```
category
cat1         [23, 98]
cat2        [65, 798]
dtype: object
```

If you need to have the result as a string, we use a simple lambda operation :

```
df.apply(lambda x: '&'.join([str(elem) for elem in x]))
```

result :

```
category
cat1         23&98
cat2        65&798
dtype: object
```